# Fade in and pulse text, pause, then fade out with CSS3 Keyframes on loop?

Tags: html, css, animation, infinite, pulse

Im having a hard time getting my head around how I could achieve the following with css keyframes.

I currently have a slideshow containing 4 slides that are on a time with keyframes and set to loop infinitely.

When each slide appears in the 'frame' i want some text to fade in and pulse just once delay and then fade out. Like this demo except I don't want to use jQuery. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/7/)

If anyone could help I'd be greatly appreciated.

I came across this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kanelbula/PB4BB/) and it's kind of what I want to achieve but i need 4

and for it to pulse. I can't get my head around how i would need to edit the keyframes.

My css for my slideshow is like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
  0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
  25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
  50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
  75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
}
@-moz-keyframes slider {
  0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
  25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
  50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
  75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
}
@keyframes slider {
  0%, 20%, 100%{ left: 0 }
  25%, 45%{ left: -100% }
  50%, 70%{ left: -200% }
  75%, 95%{ left: -300% }
}

#carousel .video-list, #descriptionCarousel .description-list {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: slider 45s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: slider 45s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
  -moz-animation: slider 45s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
  -o-animation: slider 45s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
  -ms-animation: slider 45s cubic-bezier(.93,.11,.32,.94) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="animation">
    <ul>
        <li class="one">This is</li>
        <li class="two">CSS3 looped</li>
        <li class="tree">animation</li>
        <li class="four">animation</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#animation{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
.one, .two, .tree, .four{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
.one{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: one 12s ease-in alternate infinite;
}
.two{
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: two 12s ease-in alternate infinite;
}
.tree{
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: tree 12s ease-in alternate infinite;
}
.four{
    background-color: purple;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: four 12s ease-in alternate infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes one {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    33% { opacity: 0; }
    66% { opacity: 0; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    33% { opacity: 1; }
    66% { opacity: 0; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes tree {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    33% { opacity: 0; }
    66% { opacity: 1; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes four {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    33% { opacity: 0; }
    66% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

new css

```
#animation{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
.one, .two, .tree, .four{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
}
.one{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: one 30s infinite linear;
    /*-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;*/
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .05s;
}
.two{
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: two 30s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .05s;
}
.tree{
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: tree 30s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .05s;
}
.four{
    background-color: purple;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: four 30s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .05s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes one {
    0% { opacity: 1; 
    }
    5%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1); 
    }
    10%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1); 
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    15%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    20% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        opacity: 0; 
    }


    25% { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 0; }
    35% { opacity: 0; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    45% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    55% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    65% { opacity: 0; }
    70% { opacity: 0; }
    75% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    85% { opacity: 0; }
    90% { opacity: 0; }
    95% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; }
    10% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 0; }
    20% { opacity: 0; }

    25% { opacity: 1; }
    30% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    35% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    40% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    45% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 
        opacity: 0; }


    50% { opacity: 0; }
    55% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    65% { opacity: 0; }
    70% { opacity: 0; }
    75% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    85% { opacity: 0; }
    90% { opacity: 0; }
    95% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes tree {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; }
    10% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 0; }
    20% { opacity: 0; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 0; }
    35% { opacity: 0; }    
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    45% { opacity: 0; }


    50% { opacity: 1; }
    55% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    60% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    65% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2
        opacity: 1; }
    70% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        opacity: 0; }

    75% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    85% { opacity: 0; }
    90% { opacity: 0; }
    95% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes four {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; }
    10% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 0; }
    20% { opacity: 0; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 0; }
    35% { opacity: 0; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    45% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    55% { opacity: 0; }    
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    65% { opacity: 0; }
    70% { opacity: 0; }

    75% { opacity: 1; }
    80% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    85% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    90% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        opacity: 1; }
    95% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8,0.8);
        opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, is there a way to make it so it doesn't reverse but so it goes back to the beginning? Also would I be able to integrate a pulse animation into this or would it need to be separate?

Comment: (at the moment its going 1,2,3,4,3,2,1) Also at the moment they overlap how would you do it so there is a gap between fade in and fade out?

Comment: please explain more (refers to this `-webkit-animation: four 12s infinite linear;`)

Comment: I need what you have created to fade in and pulse at the same time like the Demo in my question. Then it needs to pause and then fade out. All of this needs to happen on a loop. At the moment you've got the fade part but the transitions overlap each other and once it has done one, two, tree, four it the goes backwards? I want it to just go back to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can't seem to get that to work do you still have the jsFiddle from before?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know after editing the code you sent over I managed to get it working for what I needed so thank you for taking the time to help out :) my loose version is in this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PB4BB/164/

Comment: @avrilalejandro Is it possible to keep this CSS3-only but have it work with an indeterminate number of list items? It would be nice not to have to update the CSS if we want to change the number of items.

Comment: if you can, but to change the color necessarily need to update the css